# how to modify/update database row using wcf http json

Tags: android, json, sql-update

I am looking for way to update the database record. I am using android client to take input from user. Android client is communicating with sql database through wcf json written in c#.

I googled and also search through stackoverflow, finally come to know that I can use http PUT to update the record. I tried to implement the http PUT method in my android client and c#. 
Its working fine in c# (checked by fiddler).

I want to use json http method not xml. hence searched and didn't find any good working example.

Please help how can I implement Http Put json method in android.

**Edited**

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                      HttpPut httpPut= new HttpPut("http://10.0.2.2:4806/Service1.svc/UpdateData");
                      httpPut.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                      httpPut.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


                      JSONStringer getdat = new JSONStringer()
                            .object()
                                .key("pd")
                                    .object()
                                        .key("ID").value(txtid.getText().toString())
                                        .key("Name").value(txtname.getText().toString())
                                        .key("Project").value(txtproject.getText().toString())
                                        .key("Result").value(txttotal.getText().toString())
                                    .endObject()
                                .endObject();


                        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(getdat.toString(),"UTF-8");
                        entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));


                        entity.setContentType("application/json");

                        httpPost.setEntity(entity);


                        // Send request to WCF service
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPut);

                        Log.d("WebInvoke", "Saving : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());


                        Toast.makeText(this, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;



                    }

                }
        catch(SocketException ex)
        {
            Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + ex.getMessage());
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }

        catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        }
```

Comment: I did try some code but its not updating. updated the question. completely stuck here because its showing status 200 but still not updating the field in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, I was not making string properly for PUT method. 
so I changed

```
http://localhost:4806/Service1.svc/UpdateData
```

to

```
http://localhost:4806/Service1.svc/UpdateData/Result
```

sucessfully updated the database !